# Как вычислить границы доверительного интервала при неизвестной дисперсии на python?

Tags: python, математика, статистика

Как имея входные данные a = 0.95(уровень доверия), n = 5(Размер выборки), сама выборка(-0.406647 1.15391 -1.01899 -1.45092 -0.492494) получить границы интервала (-1.814 0.928 )?

Код для вычисления интервала. Не могу понять в чем ошибка, все делаю согласно формулам, но ответ получается немного не такой.

```
import scipy.stats as sp
import numpy as np

with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    n, a = map(lambda x: float(x), fin.readline().strip('\n').split())
    x = list(map(float, fin.readline().split()))

    xMean = np.mean(x)
    se = sp.sem(x)
    interval = se * sp.t.ppf((1-a)/2, n - 1)
    X = [xMean + interval, xMean - interval]

    print(*X, file=fout, sep=' ', end='')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В проблеме разобрался. Код для вычисления границ доверительного интервала при неизвестной дисперсии:

```
import scipy.stats as sp
import numpy as np

with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin:
    n, a = map(lambda i: float(i), fin.readline().strip('\n').split())
    x = list(map(float, fin.readline().split()))

mean = np.mean(x)
d = np.var(x, ddof=1) * n / (n - 1)
step = sp.t.ppf((a + 1) / 2, n - 1) * np.sqrt(d/n)


interval = [mean - step, mean + step]

print(*interval)
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
interval = se * sp.t.ppf((1-a)/2, n - 1)
```

на:

```
interval = se * sp.t.ppf((1+a)/2, n - 1)
# NOTE:  —————————————->   ^
```

Comment: Это меняет знаки интервала

Comment: @Dmitry, если “a” - это уровень доверия, то у меня в ответе правильная формула

Comment: Все верно а - это уровень доверия, n-кол-во элементов в выборе, х - сама выборка. При (1-а)/2 ответ: (-1.6693183375690408, 0.783261937569041), при плюсе (0.783261937569041 -1.6693183375690408) соответственно наоборот.

Comment: @Dmitry, похоже вы в ответе выдаёте интервал задом-наперёд- у вас на первом месте стоит правая граница , а на втором - левая. От вас , скорее всего ожидают наоборот

Comment: В любом случае это лишь меняет числа местами